# how to accessing public and private members of List<CustomClass>

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list, c#-4.0

You create a class that will represent a row with 2 columns:

```
public class Foo
{
    // obviously you find meaningful names of the 2 properties

    public string Column1 { get; set; } 
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then you store in a `List<Foo>`:

```
List<Foo> _items = new List<Foo>();
_items.Add(new Foo { Column1 = "bar", Column2 = "baz" });
```

How can I set the DataSource of a Listbox to items? If I do

```
ListBox1.DataSource = _items;
```

I'll see a `list of Objects` in the Listbox instead of the text that it contains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the public members, you would just iterate through the items:

```
foreach(Foo item in _items)
{
     // use item
}
```

Since your collection is a `List<T>`, you can also access the items by index:

```
string col1 = _items[0].Column1;  // First item in list's column1
```

However, you cannot access the `Foo` classes *private* members.  The entire point of making a member in `Foo` private is to prevent access from outside of the `Foo` class.

Answer (score 1):

Override ToString() method in Foo class. ListBox uses it to convert objects to strings

Sample:

```
class A

{

    public int I

    {

        get;

        set;

    }

    public override string ToString()

    {

        return "I=" + I.ToString();

    }

}



public partial class Form1 : Form

{

    public Form1()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        listBox1.DataSource = new[]

        {

            new A { I = 1},

            new A { I = 2},

        };

    }

}
```

Comment: Sounds good in theory but I maybe missing something. Can you post your code or something?

Comment: The site is blocked at work. Can you copy and paste it in your answer?

Comment: How does your example show that your listbox1.DataSource is getting data from a List<T> where T is a custom class? I am new to C# so I am getting more confused than before

Comment: It's no a List<T> but array, however should work exactly in the same way with List<T>.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `_items[42]` and/or a `foreach` loop.